# Как перейти от полноэкранного перелистывания сайта к обычному в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html5, fullpage

Как реализовать подобный переход?
http://fullpage.easyweb.su/
Данный сайт листается экранами на ПК, а при переходе в мобильную версию он листается как обычный сайт.

Answer (score 1):

Есть много готовых решений, которые реализуют данный подход (лично не подскажу не пользовался, но знаю что есть), но если интересует как это в принципе устроено и может быть реализовано, ниже пример на коленках с использование jQuery. Для мобильных устройств проверяется `userAgent` и не создаётся событие которое делает плавный переход

```js
var contBlock = $('.block');
var offset = parseInt(document.body.clientHeight / contBlock.length);
var currentScroll = 0;
var isAnimate = false;
var lastScroll = 0;
if( !/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (isAnimate) return;
  isAnimate = true;
 
  var pageOffset = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (pageOffset > lastScroll) {
   currentScroll += offset;
  }
  else {
   currentScroll -= offset;
  }
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: currentScroll
  }, 400);
  
  setTimeout(() => {
   isAnimate = false;
    pageOffset = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    lastScroll = pageOffset <= 0 ? 0 : pageOffset;
  },500);
  
});
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.brown {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="block green"></div>
  <div class="block red"></div>
  <div class="block yellow"></div>
  <div class="block brown"></div>
</body>
```